# Database using Eclipse

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am making a login screen which is connected to the database shown below, I have the class called DatabaseHelper which contains all my tables and functions, and the main.java contains the codes below, and the register.java contains the following codes :

```
package DatabaseHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ExpenseManager";

    // Table Names
    private static final String TABLE_user = "user";
    private static final String TABLE_income = "income";
    private static final String TABLE_store = "store";

    // Common column names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "uid";

    // user Table - column names
    public static final String KEY_username = "username";
    public static final String KEY_password = "password";
    private static final String KEY_email = "email";
    private static final String KEY_url = "url";
    private static final String KEY_amountalert = "amountalert";
    private static final String KEY_currency = "currency";

    // income Table - column names
    private static final String KEY_IID = "iid";
    private static final String KEY_INCOMEDATE = "Incomedate";
    private static final String KEY_AMOUNT = "amount";
    private static final String KEY_INCOMETYPE = "Incometype";

    // store Table - column names
    private static final String KEY_EID = "eid";
    private static final String KEY_ITEM = "item";
    private static final String KEY_PRICE = "price";
    private static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";
    private static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
    private static final String KEY_PLACE = "place";

    // Table Create Statements
    // user table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_user = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_user + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_username + " TEXT," + KEY_password + " TEXT," + KEY_email
            + " TEXT, " + KEY_url + " TEXT," + KEY_amountalert + " FLOAT,"
            + KEY_INCOMETYPE + " TEXT," + KEY_currency + " TEXT," + ")";

    // income table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_income = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_income + "(" + KEY_IID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_AMOUNT + " TEXT," + KEY_ID + " INTEGER," + KEY_INCOMEDATE
            + " DATETIME," + KEY_INCOMETYPE + " TEXT, " + "FOREIGN KEY ("
            + KEY_ID + ") REFERENCES TABLE_user(uid))";

    // store table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_store = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_store + "(" + KEY_EID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_ITEM
            + " TEXT," + KEY_PRICE + " FLOAT," + KEY_TYPE + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_PLACE + " TEXT, " + KEY_DATE + " DATETIME, " + KEY_ID
            + " INTEGER," + "FOREIGN KEY (" + KEY_ID
            + ") REFERENCES TABLE_user(uid))";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // creating required tables
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_user);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_income);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_store);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // on upgrade drop older tables
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_user);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_income);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_store);

        // create new tables
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public  DatabaseHelper open() {  
        return this;
    }

    public void close() { 
        db.close();
    }

    public void Login(String username,String password){
           ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            String un = (String) values.get(username);
            String ps = (String) values.get(password);
            db.close();
           }

    public void insertEntry(String username,String password, String email, String url, String amountAlert){
       ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        // Assign values for each row.
        values.put("KEY_username", username);
        values.put("KEY_password",password);
        values.put("KEY_email",email);
        values.put(KEY_url, url);
        values.put(KEY_amountalert, amountAlert);
        // Insert the row into your table
        db.insert(TABLE_user, null, values);
        db.close();
       }

}





package com.example.dailyexpensemanager;

import info.androidhive.sqlite.model.user;

public class Main extends Activity {

    private EditText username;
    private EditText password;
    private TextView attempts;
    private Button login;
    int counter = 3;

    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        attempts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        attempts.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        TextView registerScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sign);

        final String getUsername=username.getText().toString();
        final String getPassword=password.getText().toString();

        // Listening to register new account link
        registerScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Switching to Register screen
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getBaseContext());
            dbHelper.open();
            dbHelper.Login(getUsername, getPassword);

            if ((getUsername.equals(DatabaseHelper.KEY_username)) && (getPassword.equals(DatabaseHelper.KEY_password))) {
                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Redirecting...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     Intent in=new Intent(Main.this,home.class);
                     startActivity(in); 
            } else {
              Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Login failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               attempts.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); counter--;
               attempts.setText(Integer.toString(counter)); 
               if(counter==0){
               login.setEnabled(false); }
            }
            dbHelper.close();
            }
    });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}


package com.example.dailyexpensemanager;

public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {

        private EditText username;
        private EditText password;
        private EditText passwordc;
        private EditText email;
        private EditText bank;
        private EditText amount;
        Button btnRegister;

        DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.register);

              //Fill the spin
              String array_spinner[];

              array_spinner = new String[3];
              array_spinner[0] = "Lebanese Lira (L.L)";
              array_spinner[1] = "Dollar ($)";
              array_spinner[2] = "Euro (€)";

              Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin);
              ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner);
              s.setAdapter(adapter);
              //end spin filling

            // Get References of Views
            username=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_fullname);
            password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
            passwordc=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_passwordc);
            email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
            bank=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.bank);
            amount=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.amount);
            btnRegister=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

            btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String getUsername=username.getText().toString();
                String getPassword=password.getText().toString();
                String getconfirmPassword=passwordc.getText().toString();
                String getEmail=email.getText().toString();
                String getBank =bank.getText().toString();
                String getAmount=amount.getText().toString();

                dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getBaseContext());
                dbHelper.open();
                dbHelper.insertEntry(getUsername, getPassword, getEmail, getBank, getAmount);


                // check if any of the fields are vacant
                if(getUsername.equals("")||getPassword.equals("")||getconfirmPassword.equals("")||getEmail.equals("")
                        ||getBank.equals("")||getAmount.equals(""))
                {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field Vaccant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return;
                }
                // check if both password matches
                if(!getPassword.equals(getconfirmPassword))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Save the Data in Database
                    dbHelper.insertEntry(getUsername, getPassword, getEmail , getBank , getAmount );
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Successfully Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                dbHelper.close();
            }
        });
    }

        }
```

When running the application, it runs normally, my problem is, when pressing on login or on register button, the application will stop unexpectally. Please I want a solution for this problem .

Comment: Can you please give us only the relevant code, giving us your whole classes is counter productive and won't help you get answers.

Comment: I don't know where is the problem, that's why I put these codes here.

Comment: What does this have to do with Eclipse? Also - post the logcat showing the error / exception you're getting.

Comment: @Squonk I am using eclipse

Comment: @Angel : Eclipse is just a development tool. It has nothing to do with the fact you have errors in your code.

Comment: @Squonk sry it's the first time I use it, I have a senior project and I still learn how to deal with it.

Comment: Why you don't use the debugger to see in which line the problem is?

Comment: @StathisAndronikos I am a beginner, how to use debugger?

Comment: If you use eclipse, let's say for example, on youtube watch a video for only 5 minutes as a tutorial and you life will change completely. Trust me and give a try.

Answer (score 1):

There's an error here:

```
KEY_currency + " TEXT," + ")";
```

Please remove the extra comma:

```
KEY_currency + " TEXT" + ")";
```

**[EDIT]**

Here's another error (it occurs twice in your code)

```
REFERENCES TABLE_user(uid))";
```

It should be

```
REFERENCES user(uid))";
```